# knockout textinput modify observeable not updating text

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i´m using textinput data-binding off the latest knockout version.
 on an input like:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="name" data-bind="textinput:vm.found().term">
```

and it works just like a charme, problem:

when i modify the value with some other script like:

```
vm.found().term("somecontent")
```

the input does not change?
i need the value of the textinput to change when i change the observable 
the doc says nothing about [textInput](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html)

Comment: Can you please provide you model javascript, or better yet a jsfiddle? You haven't provided how the model is declared. My js fiddle shows the binding working: http://jsfiddle.net/3o8gufz1/

Answer (score 1):

You should never have raw, deeply nested bindings like you have there.  Assuming the `found` value has changed, it the text box will still be bound to the previous `found` object.  You probably should be using a `with` binding somewhere.

```
<div data-bind="with: vm.found">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" data-bind="textinput: term">
</div>
```